# Change sets for un-related orgs?

Tags: change-set

Can I use a change set to connect 2 developer orgs? basically any two orgs that are un-related?

Just trying to see what the limitation of Change sets are

Comment: No, you can't change sets has to be within the same org .... deployment connection is required [reference](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets.htm&language=en_US)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change sets can only transfer elements between a production org and sandboxes created in that production org. The other two primary means of transferring metadata, packages and the API, are the only ways to transfer metadata between orgs that are not connected by the production-sandbox relationship. The primary advantages of change sets is that they can transfer elements that already have the same name (e.g. to update picklist values or page layouts), and can easily migrate selected user permissions simply by including profiles. Packages don't allow updating existing elements, except for managed packages, which are primarily of interest to ISVs, while the metadata API is the most commonly used method of transferring metadata between orgs that are not connected by change sets.